# Splitting data from a file into arrays - C

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, storing-data

I've got a .txt file called songs.txt and I'm trying to devise a way where I can open and read the contents of this file, and then sort the input by artist name and then by song title and print it out in the following format:

```
File contents:                                              Desired output format:

Bon Iver                                                    Arcade Fire
29 #Strafford APTS***4:05                                   o Cold Wind***3:12
00000 Million***3:53                                        o Rebellion (Lies)***5:10
re: Stacks***6:40                                           o Neighborhood #1 (Tunnels)***4:48
                                                            o Neighborhood #3 (Power Out)***5:12
Future Islands                                              o Wake Up***5:39
Tin Man***3:14                                            
Seasons (Waiting on You)***3:46                             Bon Iver
Grease***4:35                                               o 00000 Million***3:53
Spirit***4:22                                               o 29 #Strafford APTS***4:05
                                                            o re: Stacks***6:40
Arcade Fire                                               
Rebellion (Lies)***5:10                                     Future Islands
Wake Up***5:39                                              o Grease***4:35
Cold Wind***3:12                                            o Seasons (Waiting on You)***3:46
Neighborhood #1 (Tunnels)***4:48                            o Spirit***4:22
Neighborhood #3 (Power Out)***5:12                          o Tin Man***3:14
```

And finally, my goal is to create a new list where this list is now shuffled and the new list doesn't exceed a certain time duration along with other specifications such as no triple play in this format:

```
Randomised playlist
Artist name: "Song title" (Song duration)
Artist name: "Song title" (Song duration)
...
Artist name: "Song title" (Song duration)
Total duration: <Total duration>.
```

But that's a battle for another day.

However, in order to do this I know, I have to read in the contents of the file, split the strings and store the artists, their respective songs, and each song duration in what I'm assuming needs to be a 2-D array.
My code so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 9999

int main(void) {
 
   char *strFileSummary = "output.txt";
   char strTempData[MAX_LEN];
   char **strData = NULL; // String List
   int i, j, min;
   int noOfLines = 0;

   FILE * ptrSummary = NULL;
   FILE *fp = fopen("songs.txt", "r+");            //this will create and open a new .txt file where the contents will be copied to

   //This will check in case the input .txt file exists or not
   if ((fp = fopen("songs.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
      printf("Um....are you sure this file exists? Maybe try again after obtaining this file.\n");
      exit(0);                                                            //This will exit the program
   }
   
   // Read and store in a string list.
   while(fgets(strTempData, MAX_LEN, fp) != NULL) {
      // Remove the trailing newline character
      if(strchr(strTempData,'\n')){
      strTempData[strlen(strTempData)-1] = '\0';
      }
      strData = (char**)realloc(strData, sizeof(char**)*(noOfLines+1));
      strData[noOfLines] = (char*)calloc(MAX_LEN,sizeof(char));
      strcpy(strData[noOfLines], strTempData);
      noOfLines++;
   }
   
   // Sort the array.
   for(int i= 0; i < (noOfLines - 1); i++) {
      int min = i;
      for(int j = i+1; j < ( noOfLines); j++) {
         if(strcmp(strData[j], strData[min]) < 0) {
            strcpy(strTempData, strData[j]);
            strcpy(strData[j], strData[min]);
            strcpy(strData[min], strTempData);
         }
      }
   }

   // Write it to outfile. file.
   for(int i = 0; i < noOfLines; i++) {
      printf("%s\n",strData[i]);
   }

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

And this produces this:

```
00000 Million***3:53
29 #Strafford APTS***4:05
Arcade Fire
Bon Iver
Cold Wind***3:12
Future Islands
Grease***4:35
Neighborhood #1 (Tunnels)***4:48
Neighborhood #3 (Power Out)***5:12
Rebellion (Lies)***5:10
Seasons (Waiting on You)***3:46
Spirit***4:22
Tin Man***3:14
Wake Up***5:39
re: Stacks***6:40
```

I'm really stuck and I can't think of a way to properly store the contents so I can use them later on, any advice/tips?

Comment: I think that what you need is a structure containing a field fo every info you need. Then you could read line by line. In the first line you expect to find the artist for the following songs, then you expect a song for every line until an empty line is found. For every song, search for `***` using `strstr` and split title and duration. Finally for each song copy artist, title and duration in a new struct element.

Comment: The temptation is to suggest that you use a 'real' database instead of your flat file:)

Comment: Yeah - what @RobertoCaboni says.  You need a 'songsByWriter' struct that contains a sublist of song data.  You can then create a list of pointers to the structs as you read in the data.  Get that working first, (so that you can recreate the original file), then sort each struct song data by title, then sort the pointers by writer.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

it's a good question for both algorithm and data structures. There is a million way of solving this problem.

I suggest you to think about the input file and find easier way to work on it. I'll write a pseudo code for potential solution.

As we can see artists and songs seperated by new lines. And songs has special character asterix in their line.

```
read the file
get the new line 
if doesn't have * and its includes a-b A-Z then its artist
put artist_name into a variable (in loop)
if the line has * inside it then its a song
you need to parse it in to song_name and duration
strtok *** (or write your own function) 
concatenate "artist_name: song_name duration"
store it inside a string and put it into outputarray
iterate other line
when eof
shuffle output array and write it out to output.txt
```

This pseudocode should work for sure, its easier then your approac because you don't need to mess with double-dimension arrays you just have 1 while loop. I hope this helps, for further help i'm here.

I worked on your problem and want to give you better sight. I used above psedo code and generated this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int isBlank (char const * line)
{
  char * ch;
  int is_blank = -1;

  // Iterate through each character.
  for (ch = line; *ch != '\0'; ++ch)
  {
    if (!isspace(*ch))
    {
      // Found a non-whitespace character.
      is_blank = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  return is_blank;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE * fp;

        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;       
        int end_song_name; // end index of song name
        int start_song_duration; // start index of duration
        char artist_name[100];
        char song_name[100]; // variable to store song name
        char duration[100]; // variable to store duration
        char last_line[200];

        fp = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

            char * asterix="***"; 
            last_line[0]='\0';
            if(isBlank(line)== -1) // checking blank, if blank skip this iteration
                continue;

            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // deleting new line character

            char *ptr;
            if(ptr=strstr(line,asterix)==NULL)  // if no asterix inside the string then its artist name
            {
                strcpy(artist_name,line);
                continue;
            }

            // Song parsing section

            int asterix_index = strcspn(line, asterix); // getting asterix index by strcspn
            int duration_start = asterix_index+3;   // duration starts 3 index after first asterix
        
            for(int i = 0; i < asterix_index; i++)
            {
                song_name[i]=line[i]; // copying line to the song_name till the asterix
            }
            song_name[asterix_index]='\0'; // adding null terminator
            

            // Duration parsing section

            int j=0;
            for(int i = duration_start; i<strlen(line); i++)
            {
                duration[j] = line[i];
                j++;
            }
            duration[j]='\0';

            printf("%s %s %s \n", artist_name, song_name, duration);
            
        }
        

        fclose(fp);
        if (line)
            free(line);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return 0;
}
```

output is below: [image]

I want you to try to understand pseudo code and see you don't need to much complicate algorithms to manage this. Think this for line by line iteration problem. Further more u need to shuffle it and put it inside an output txt. I'm here for further help.

I hope this helps.